# How to set listindex of combo corresponding to fullname?

Tags: oracle, vb6

Here in my application I am performing 2 tasks:

1. display all values on `cmbrno_click()`
2. display all values on `cmbfulnm_lostfocus()`

`cmbrno`'s style is set to 2-dropdown list.

```vb
Private Sub CmbFulNM_LostFocus()
  RES.Open "student_record_database",CON,adOpenDynamic,adLockOptimistic,adCmdTable

  For i = 0 To RES.RecordCount - 1
    CmbRNO.Text = RES!ROLLNO 'at this line control goes to the cmbrno_click event which is having same part of coding and executes that also.
    TxtFNM.Text = RES!FIRST_NAME 'error like: item not fount in corresponding ordinal
    TxtMIDNM.Text = RES!MIDDLE_NAME
    TxtLNM.Text = RES!LAST_NAME
    TxtADDR.Text = RES!ADDRESS
    COMBO1.Text = RES!GRADE
    CmbDiv.Text = RES!DIV
    CmbBG.Text = RES!BLOOD_GROUP

    If CmbRNO.ListCount > 0 Then CmbRNO.ListIndex = i
  Next i
  RES.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all rather muddled. The subject of this posting is : "How to set listindex of combo corresponding to fullname?"
However, the (C) comment in the code is: "//error like: item not fount in corresponding ordinal.". You will have to provide the *exact* error message, not one you think it is "like".

Is TxtFNM really a text box? You should be describing what these controls are, and how these controls are being initialised.

Using psychic debugging, your problem might be that you haven't spelled the field name correctly. Is it really "FIRST_NAME"?

On a different note, I notice that you are looping through multiple records, copying each field into the same controls. Since there is no MoveNext, this code will always return the first record, irrespective of the nubmer of records. However, thanks to the line immediately before "Next i", you will be potentially overwriting the selection of cmbRNO at the start of the loop with the *i*'th added item.

Perhaps you should actually state what you want to do here. "[2]display all values on cmbfulnm_lostfocus()" isn't very precise.